# Web search for pages written in Mongolian

Tags: gratis, search-engine, language

I need a search engine that can search for web pages written in Mongolian (preferably Cyrillic, not traditional script).

If I start an anonymous browsing session at google.mn, and type in "эндрю" (without quotes), I get a lot of results from .ru which I assume are written in Russian, even though the configuration settings say it's only showing pages written in Mongolian.

The product should be free of charge, and preferably available on the web.